# Using navwalker bootstrap menu in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find a perfect middle when it comes to using bootstrap menu and navwalker on desktop and mobile devices.

I cant get it to work to show sub-sub menu items (ie main menu item has children and one of the children has its children). Everything works on mobile but children are not displayed on desktop.

My code in header looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-docs-nav col-md-9" role="banner">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
                        </div>

                            <?php
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                                    'depth'             => 3,
                                    'container'         => 'nav',
                                    'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse',
                                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav no-gutter',
                                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                );
                            ?>
```

If I add some styling to enable hover I help only desktop devices as there is no hover on mobile like this:

```
.menu-item-has-children:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}   

.dropdown-menu>.active>a, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover {
    background-color: $red-color !important;
}
```

Any ideas how to make it happen?

Comment: Bootstrap nav walker works for only one level. Check https://github.com/jeffmould/multi-level-bootstrap-menu for multilevel

Comment: this is a solution in some way but the 3rd level doesn't work. Any advices?